# How do I compare 2 arrays to see if they have the same contents?

Tags: c++, c++11, multidimensional-array

My code works so far but I have a logic error in the 17th to 30th line of code and I can't seem to figure it out. I feel like I have too much going on.

The prompt for the problem is as follows:

Two two-dimensional arrays `m1` and `m2` are identical if they have the same contents. Write a function that returns true if `m1` and `m2` are identical, using the following header:

```
const int SIZE = 3;    

bool equals(const int m1[][SIZE], const int m2[][SIZE]);
```

Write a test program that prompts the user to enter two 3 x3 arrays of integers and displays whether the two are identical. Here are the sample runs (below).

---

```
Enter m1: 51 25 22 6 1 4 24 54 6

Enter m2: 52 22 25 6 1 4 24 54 6

output : Two arrays are identical

Enter m1: 51 5 22 6 1 4 24 54 6

Enter m2: 51 22 25 6 1 4 24 54 6

output: Two arrays are not identical
```

---

This is my code (sorry if it is bad and messy im still learning)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

const int SIZE = 3;

bool equals(const int m1[][SIZE], const int m2[][SIZE]) {

    bool choice = true;

    while (choice) {
        for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++) {
                if (m1[i][j] != m2[i][j]) {                                                        // code is fine until here. There is a logic error somewhere. m1: 123456789 m2: 987654321 output: array not identical
                    for (int k = 0; k < SIZE; k++) {
                        for (int h = 0; h < SIZE; h++) {
                            if (m1[i][j] == m2[k][h]) {
                                return true;
                            }
                            else {
                                choice = false;
                                return false;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                else {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }

    }
}

int main() {

    string input1, input2, num1, num2;
    int count1 = 0, count2 = 0;
    int a = 0, b = 0, c = 0;
    int a2 = 0, b2 = 0, c2 = 0;
    int arr1[SIZE][SIZE];
    int arr2[SIZE][SIZE];

    cout << "Enter m1: ";
    getline(cin, input1);
    stringstream line1(input1);

    cout << "Enter m2: ";
    getline(cin, input2);
    stringstream line2(input2);

    while (line1 >> num1) {

        if (count1 < 3) {
            stringstream(num1) >> arr1[0][a];
            a++;
        }
        else if (count1 >= 3 && count1 <= 5) {
            stringstream(num1) >> arr1[1][b];
            b++;
        }
        else {
            stringstream(num1) >> arr1[2][c];
            c++;
        }
        count1++;
    }

    while (line2 >> num2) {

        if (count2 < 3) {
            stringstream(num2) >> arr2[0][a2];
            a2++;
        }
        else if (count2 >= 3 && count2 <= 5) {
            stringstream(num2) >> arr2[1][b2];
            b2++;
        }
        else {
            stringstream(num2) >> arr2[2][c2];
            c2++;
        }
        count2++;
    }

    bool answer = equals(arr1, arr2);

   if (answer) {
        cout << "Two arrays are identical" << endl;
   }
   else {
        cout << "Two arrays are not identical" << endl;
   }

   system("Pause");

   return 0;
}
```

Thank You

Comment: Surely it only takes *one* difference to return false?

Comment: Why are you using that `while`? Why do you have so many nested `for`s? If you want to compare 2 dimensional array, think of it as table with rows and collumns. You have to iterate over rows and in each row iterate over columns. That means, only 2 nested `for`s are required

Comment: Since you have nice statically allocated and contiguous arrays of a simple data type, consider using `memcmp`. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memcmp

Answer (score 0):

You do have a lot going on in that function. You have lots of nested loops.

What you can do to make a code a bit more easier to understand is just check for the false condition using only two for loops (nested). If you encounter it, return false. If the false condition is not encountered, you will leave the loop at some point and then you make sure to encounter the return true statement.

```
for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i)
    for(int j = 0; j <SIZE; ++j)
        if (m1[i][j] != m2[i][j])
            return false;

return true;
```

This is how I would write that function. 
These are some of the redundancies you have in your function:

- The while loop. What purpose does that serve? You already have a for loop that will run until end conditions are met.
- Another set of for loops inside the first if condition.

And your function returns true even when the required conditions are not met. Your line 21 will return true even when a1[1][2] is equal to a2[3][3]. This shouldn't be the case.

One way you can find out these mistakes is by working out test cases on a piece of paper.

I hope I helped! (and I hope I am right) :)

Comment: For the sake of readability and for the new coders, may I recommend putting in the braces to make the scoping explicit and obvious?